# Cloud Sync service for app

Tags: html, cloud, jsonp, synchronization

Hi I have an HTML5 app which has a User Login. The app has a Notes option. I am looking for a service which would help me to sync the notes for that user account. So the same user can login in a different device and see the Notes in their device. I cannot use iCloud as Android doesnt support it.

We tried to store the notes in the user db using jsonp but still had some issues.

Someone mentioned about Pusher.com but looks like the service is expensive for a starter like us. Is there any more reliable and cheap options for us? W

Answer (score 0):

[Parse](http://www.parse.com) is probably more in line with what you are looking for. Pusher provides a service for sending push notifications, but you mentioned the need to store data in the cloud. Parse can accomplish this and does have a free basic plan that you can get started with.

Comment: Thanks, that really looks promising!